# Can I use multiple and different databases in the same Quarkus app?

Tags: java, mysql, postgresql, hibernate, quarkus

I want my Quarkus app to connect to both a PostgreSQL database and a MySQL database.

I've researched through https://quarkus.io/guides/datasource#multiple-datasources and https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm#multitenancy, but could not figure out if this is possible.

my application.properties is as below;

```
quarkus.datasource.postgresql.db-kind=postgresql
quarkus.datasource.postgresql.username=xyz
quarkus.datasource.postgresql.password=xyz
quarkus.datasource.postgresql.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/xyz

quarkus.datasource.mysql.db-kind=mysql
quarkus.datasource.mysql.username=xyz
quarkus.datasource.mysql.password=xyz
quarkus.datasource.mysql.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3305/xyz
```

my pom.xml has both;

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-mysql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

1. Is it possible to connect to multiple different types of database from Quarkus?
2. How do I persist() an Entity to the correct database if such capability exists?
   Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is supported, see [this](https://quarkus.io/guides/datasource#multiple-datasources) part of the datasource documentation and [this](https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm#multiple-persistence-units) part of the Hibernate ORM documentation.